# Translation of bye (formal) in Italian

Tags: translation, phrase-request

I want to say good-bye to my professor but I said "salve". "Salve" is to say hi and is formal (more than "ciao"). Then she said that it was not "salve" but did not tell me how to say good-bye. So can anybody tell me how to say it please? :)

Comment: Please, avoid phrases like “respond asap”: nobody here is paid for helping you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Arrivederci" is the most appropriate form to say goodbye to someone if you're in a formal context: please note that it theoretically expresses a wish to see the person you've talked to again; if you're on the phone, you could use "A risentirci" instead.
If you're looking for something even more formal, you can use "A rivederLa".

Comment: To a professor (or anyone formal-speaking person), I'd use "arrivederLa" (note the capital letter on the L). That's because the formal Italian uses the 3rd person singular feminine. The capital letter is mandatory for writing, also because formal requires capitals.

Comment: @MarioVernari you're right, I've updated my answer

Comment: @MarioVernari How do you make clear that you're saying `arrivederLa` with a capital L? `;-)` I find that usage of capital letters very bureaucratic and not at all mandatory: the third person is sufficient.

Comment: @egreg I should dig, but you might be right on the improper "mandatory". I learned yet always used the capital letter for formality, and also always read in that way.

Comment: @MarioVernari It's “mandatory” in bureaucratic style; it shows (false) deference or even (false) submissiveness, particularly when accompanied with “la Signoria Vostra” when “lei” would suffice. If I were to report a dialogue, I'd write “arrivederla” with no doubt.

Comment: At the moment I don't have time to search, but here is a common formal letter for a CV. Any reference to the person is made using the capital letter. http://www.oneworlditaliano.com/grammatica-italiana/lettere_formali.htm

Comment: @egreg: by your argument (false deference and false submissiveness) why use the third person at all? I prefer to write it correctly, with a capital L (or a capital S, in the case of Suo/Sua). It also helps in disambiguating, sometimes.

Comment: @MarioVernari I see (wrong) capitals only in the final line.

Comment: In my experience the capital letter is just for formal commercial letters, but actually Accademia della Crusca and Treccani say that it's required http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/pronomi-cortesia http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-allocutivi_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/ . Anyway, I think that in most of the formal uses Arrivederci is acceptable